# Как изменить заголовок в xaml с помощью c# скрипта

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Я пытался использовать "Binding", но текст не отображается.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlSamples;assembly=XamlSamples"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.MainWindow"
             Title="{Binding myProperty}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="test"                
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XamlSamples
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainWindow : ContentPage
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string myProperty { get; } = "MY TEXT";
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А DataContext кто указывать будет?

Answer (score 0):

прочитав в сотый раз документацию майков, я понял, что я идиот.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : ContentPage
    {
        //public Property myProperty { get; set; }

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label.BindingContext = "test";


        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlSamples;assembly=XamlSamples"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.MainWindow"
             Title= "test">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding}" 
                   x:Name="label"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndE`введите сюда код`xpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow : ContentPage
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = "test";
    }
}
```